# How do I parse JSON sprinkled unpredictably into a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Suppose that I've got a node.js application that receives input in a weird format: strings with JSON arbitrarily sprinkled into them, like so:

`This is a string {"with":"json","in":"it"} followed by more text {"and":{"some":["more","json"]}} and more text`

I have a couple guarantees about this input text:

1. The bits of literal text in between the JSON objects are always free from curly braces.
2. The top level JSON objects shoved into the text are always object literals, never arrays.

My goal is to split this into an array, with the literal text left alone and the JSON parsed out, like this:

```
[
    "This is a string ",
    {"with":"json","in":"it"},
    " followed by more text ",
    {"and":{"some":["more","json"]}},
    " and more text"
]
```

So far I've written a [naive solution](https://hastebin.com/igugugotah.js) that simply counts curly braces to decide where the JSON starts and stops. But this wouldn't work if the JSON contains strings with curly braces in them `{"like":"this one } right here"}`. I could try to get around that by doing similar quote counting math, but then I also have to account for escaped quotes. At that point it feels like I'm redoing way too much of `JSON.parse`'s job. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: There is no foolproof way to do this short of writing a full-blown parser yourself.

Comment: Wow, that's a nightmare of a data format.  You could maybe brute-force it by starting from each `{`, greedy-matching to the last `}`, then backtracking until  JSON.parse stops throwing errors on the contents; rinse and repeat.  Computationally expensive (and ridiculous) but at least you wouldn't have to write your own parser.

Comment: _"strings with JSON arbitrarily sprinkled into them, like so:"_ Note,  `"This is a string "` is valid `JSON`.

Comment: Does the actual input data contain space characters following the comma,  between the keys _`{"with":"json", "in":"it"}`_ ?

Comment: @guest271314 Not in my case, in practice. In principle it would still be valid JSON if it contained such whitespace. I edited the space out to avoid any future confusion.

Comment: If the input is known to be safe, you might want to just `eval()` the whole thing and then you can access it as a Javascript object and let the Javascript parser parse it for you.  But, if the input can't be trusted to not contain malicious code, then you will have to write your own string parser to sort out the strings from the objects.

Comment: "Is there a better way to solve this problem?" - Any chance you can contact the guys who generate that input and ask them to work decently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a comparatively simple brute-force approach:  split the whole input string on curly braces, then step through the array in order.  Whenever you come across an open brace, find the longest chunk of the array from that starting point that successfully parses as JSON. Rinse and repeat.

This will *not* work if the input contains invalid JSON and/or unbalanced braces (see the last two test cases below.)

```js
const tryJSON = input => {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(input);
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

const parse = input => {
  let output = [];
  let chunks = input.split(/([{}])/);

  for (let i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
    if (chunks[i] === '{') {
      // found some possible JSON; start at the last } and backtrack until it works.
      for (let j = chunks.lastIndexOf('}'); j > i; j--) {
        if (chunks[j] === '}') {
          // Does it blend?
          let parsed = tryJSON(chunks.slice(i, j + 1).join(""))
          if (parsed) {
            // it does! Grab the whole thing and skip ahead
            output.push(parsed);
            i = j;
          }
        }
      }
    } else if (chunks[i]) {
      // neither JSON nor empty
      output.push(chunks[i])
    }
  }

  console.log(output)
  return output
}

parse(`{"foo": "bar"}`)
parse(`test{"foo": "b}ar{{[[[{}}}}{}{}}"}`)
parse(`this {"is": "a st}ri{ng"} with {"json": ["in", "i{t"]}`)
parse(`{}`)
parse(`this {"i{s": invalid}`)
parse(`So is {this: "one"}`)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can check if JSON.parse throws an error to determine if the chunk is a valid JSON object or not. If it throws an error then the unquoted `}` are unbalanced:

```js
const tests = [
  '{"just":"json }}{}{}{{[]}}}}","x":[1,2,3]}',
  'Just a string',
  'This string has a tricky case: {"like":"this one } right here"}',
  'This string {} has a tiny JSON object in it.',
  '.{}.',
  'This is a string {"with":"json","in":"it"} followed by more text {"and":{"some":["more","json"]}} and more text',
];

tests.forEach( test => console.log( parse_json_interleaved_string( test ) ) );

function parse_json_interleaved_string ( str ) {
  const chunks = [ ];
  let last_json_end_index = -1;
  let json_index = str.indexOf( '{', last_json_end_index + 1 );
  for ( ; json_index !== -1; json_index = str.indexOf( '{', last_json_end_index + 1 ) ) {

    // Push the plain string before the JSON
    if ( json_index !== last_json_end_index + 1 )
        chunks.push( str.substring( last_json_end_index, json_index ) );

    let json_end_index = str.indexOf( '}', json_index + 1 );

    // Find the end of the JSON
    while ( true ) {
       try { 
         JSON.parse( str.substring( json_index, json_end_index + 1 ) );
         break;
       } catch ( e ) {
         json_end_index = str.indexOf( '}', json_end_index + 1 );
         if ( json_end_index === -1 )
           throw new Error( 'Unterminated JSON object in string' );
       }
    }

    // Push JSON
    chunks.push( str.substring( json_index, json_end_index + 1 ) );
    last_json_end_index = json_end_index + 1;
  }

  // Push final plain string if any
  if ( last_json_end_index === - 1 )
    chunks.push( str );
  else if ( str.length !== last_json_end_index )
    chunks.push( str.substr( last_json_end_index ) );

  return chunks;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I could try to get around that by doing similar quote counting math, but then I also have to account for escaped quotes. At that point it feels like I'm redoing way too much of JSON.parse's job. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

I don't think so. Your input is pretty far from JSON.
But accounting for all those things isn't that hard.

The following snippet should work:

```js
function construct(str) {
  const len = str.length
  let lastSavedIndex = -1
  let bracketLevel = 0
  let inJsonString = false
  let lastCharWasEscapeChar = false
  
  let result = []
  
  for(let i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    if(bracketLevel !== 0 && !lastCharWasEscapeChar && str[i] === '"') {
      inJsonString = !inJsonString
    }
    else if (!inJsonString && str[i] === '{') {
      if (bracketLevel === 0) {
        result.push(str.substring(lastSavedIndex + 1, i))
        lastSavedIndex = i - 1
      }
      
      ++bracketLevel
    }
    else if (!inJsonString && str[i] === '}') {
      --bracketLevel
      
      if (bracketLevel === 0) {
        result.push(JSON.parse(str.substring(lastSavedIndex + 1, i + 1)))
        lastSavedIndex = i
      }
    }
    else if (inJsonString && str[i] === '\\') {
      lastCharWasEscapeChar = !lastCharWasEscapeChar
    }
    else {
      lastCharWasEscapeChar = false
    }
  }
  if(lastSavedIndex !== len -1) {
    result.push(str.substring(lastSavedIndex + 1, len))
  }
  return result
}


const standardText = 'This is a string {"with":"json","in":"it"} followed by more text {"and":{"some":["more","json"]}} and more text. {"foo": "bar}"}'

const inputTA = document.getElementById('input')
const outputDiv = document.getElementById('output')

function updateOutput() {
  outputDiv.innerText =
    JSON.stringify(
      construct(inputTA.value),
      null,
      2
    )
}

inputTA.oninput = updateOutput
inputTA.value = standardText
updateOutput()
```

```html
<textarea id="input" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>

<pre id="output"><pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you one approach that iterates char by char. First we create an array from the input and then use `reduce()` on it. When we detect an opening curly bracket `{` we push the current accumulated chunk on an array of detected results, and then we set a flag on the `accumulator` object we are using on `reduce`. While this flag is set to `true` we will try to parse for a `JSON` and only when success we put the `chunk` representing the `JSON` on the array of detected results and set the flag again to `false`.

The `accumulator` of the `reduce()` method will hold next data:

1. `res`: an array with detected results: `strings` or `jsons`.
2. `chunk`: a string representing the current accumulated chunk of chars.
3. `isJson`: a boolean indicating if the current `chunk` is `json` or not.

```js
const input = 'This is a string {"with":"json", "in":"it"} followed by more text {"and":{"some":["more","json","data"]}} and more text';

let obj = Array.from(input).reduce(({res, isJson, chunk}, curr) =>
{
    if (curr === "{")
    {
        if (!isJson) res.push(chunk);
        chunk = isJson ? chunk + curr : curr;
        isJson = true;
    }
    else if (isJson)
    {
        try
        {
            chunk += curr;
            JSON.parse(chunk);

            // If no error, we found a JSON.
            res.push(chunk);
            chunk = "";
            isJson = false;
        }
        catch(e) {/* Ignore error */}
    }
    else
    {
        chunk += curr;
    }

    return {res, isJson, chunk};

}, {res:[], isJson:false, chunk:""})

// First stage done, lets debug obtained data.

obj.res.push(obj.chunk);
console.log(obj.res);

// Finally, we map the pieces.

let res = obj.res.map(x => x.match("{") ? JSON.parse(x) : x);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegExp` `/(\s(?=[{]))|\s(?=[\w\s]+[{])/ig` to `.split()` space character followed by opening curly brace `{` or space character followed by one or more word or space characters followed by opening curly brace, `.filter()` to remove `undefined` values from resulting array, create a new array, then `while` the resulting split array has `.length` get the index where the value contains only space characters, `.splice()` the beginning of the matched array to the index plus `1`, if array `.length` is `0` `.push()` empty string `''` else space character `' '` with match `.join()`ed by space character `' '` `.replace()` last space character and `.shift()` matched array, which is `JSON`, then next element of the matched array.

```js
const str = `This is a string {"with":"json","in":"it"} followed by more text {"and":{"some":["more","json"]}} and more text {"like":"this one } right here"}`;

const formatStringContainingJSON = s => {
  const r = /(\s(?=[{]))|\s(?=[\w\s]+[{])/ig;
  const matches = s.split(r).filter(Boolean);
  const res = [];
  while (matches.length) {
    const index = matches.findIndex(s => /^\s+$/.test(s));
    const match =  matches.splice(0, index + 1);
    res.push(
      `${!res.length ? '' : ' '}${match.join(' ').replace(/\s$/, '')}`
    , `${matches.shift()}`
    );
  };
  return res;
}

let result = formatStringContainingJSON(str);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory answer: this is an improper format (because of this complication, and the guarantee is a security hole if the parser is improperly designed); it should ideally be redesigned. (Sorry, it had to be said.)

Barring that, you can generate a parser using your favorite parser generator that outputs to javascript as a target language. It might even have a [demo](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/json/JSON.g4) grammar for JSON.

However, the glaring security issue is incredibly scary (if any JSON gets past the 'guarantee', suddenly it's a vector). An array interspersed representation seems nicer, with the constraint that `assert(text.length == markup.length+1)`:

```
'{
    "text": ['Hello', 'this is red text!'],
    "markup": [{"text":"everyone", "color":"red"}]
}'
```

or even nicer:

```
'[
    {"type":"text", "text":"Hello"},
    {"type":"markup", "text":"everyone", "color":"red"}    # or  ,"val":{"text":.., "color":..}}
    {"type":"text", "text":"this is red text!"},
    ...
]'
```

Store compressed ideally. Unserialize without any worries with JSON.parse.