# Detect end of json object using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a string that starts with a JSON object but after the end of which the string goes on (something like `{"a":"fdfsd","b":5}ghresd`). The text afterward can contain any character and the JSON can be anything allowed for a JSON.

I would like to deserialize the JSON object and know where it ends because I want to process the rest of the string afterward, how do I do that, preferably using `Newtonsoft.Json`?

Comment: You might find the answers to my earlier, related question helpful, although in that case I was working in JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54608178/how-do-i-parse-json-sprinkled-unpredictably-into-a-string

Comment: Does the string contain } after the json-object? Hopefully not. Then you could use Parse with yourString.SubString(0,yourString.LastIndexOf('}')) as parameter.

Comment: How about getting everything from the first `{` and then the last index of `}`... this could be your json and the rest you can deal with then. Also you could verify it's valid json as well using `JToken.Parse`...

Comment: You can discard the characters after the end as shown in [Discarding garbage characters after json object with Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37172263/3744182), however `JsonTextReader` buffers its content, and doesn't have any mechanism to report the current character position.

Comment: @R.Davidson I was aware of the possibility to do this, but hoped for an easier solution, thanks anyway

Comment: @TobiasBrohl true, but what about the additional content the OP needs, still, the string will have to be parsed...

Comment: @dbc thanks, but that won't help me either, due to the limitation mentioned

Comment: @Nikolaus Yes it can contain curly brackets and any other character, so it wont work that way

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Tobias Brohl is OP.

Comment: @Nikolaus a possibly dumb question: Whats meant by OP?

Comment: Related unanswered question: [How to get detailed position information from JsonTextReader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53108483).  Maybe you could open an enhancement request on https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues asking to track the position in the underlying text reader?

Comment: @Nikolaus shoot, wrong tagged person hahah I meant @ dbc...

Comment: @Tobias Brohl the meaning of OP in this context is 'Original Poster'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make use of the [`SupportMultipleContent`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_SupportMultipleContent.htm) property, for example:

```
var json = "{\"a\":\"fdfsd\",\"b\":5}ghresd";

var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

//Read the first JSON fragment
reader.Read();

var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
var result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);

//Or if you have a class to deserialise into:
//var result = serializer.Deserialize<YourClassHere>(reader);

//Line position is where the reader got up to in the JSON string
var extraData = json.Substring(reader.LinePosition);
```

Comment: Checking this but seems great

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code might not work as expected if your `json` has multiple lines:

```cs
var extraData = json.Substring(reader.LinePosition);
```

You might need to consider adding additional check:

```cs
if(reader.LineNumber != 1)
  throw new NotSupportedException("Multiline JSON objects are not supported.");
```

Or you can take that value from private field using `Reflection`:

```cs
var charPosition = (int)reader.GetType().GetField("_charPos", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(reader);
```

[JsonTextReader source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs)